# How to derive the right solution for a linear differential equation of an RC-circuit-like system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, physics, electromagnetism

In the picture below.
Does anyone knows why all 3 answers are correct and not just answer 2?
Doesn't the answer have to be a negative exponent function?
[image]

Comment: Alot of your tags don't make sense - neural networks amd dynamical systems.

Comment: Where did the $9.5$ in answer 2 come from?

Comment: @Ofek Gillon it doesn't matter, I think, the problem talks about possible solutions. Anyway, I'd like to get the link to that page :)